# How to position images over a background in a div element?

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

Just to preface things, I'm very, very new to HTML and CSS.

For a fun project, I would like to overlay individual images over a background from popular video game. However I'm having problems with the formatting and positioning. The sizing of the background keeps changing and I'm not sure how to make it responsive. Additionally, I'm not sure what the best way to proceed with the positioning of images is. I've just been adjusting the margins of the picture but I'm not sure it's the best way of doing it.

Any advice would be welcome!

Comment: Please provide some code - what you have so far.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, if you post the code you have so far and tell us what have you already tried. we will be able to offer better advice

Comment: as for your question "I'm not sure what the best way to proceed with the positioning of images"

ill suguest to use either absolute positioning or relative positioning, as it will let you especify the ubication of your image in  xy coordinates

Comment: @JuanAntonioOrozco it's waaay to early to start suggesting absolute positioning as a solution. OP might only need a CSS grid with a background image applied to the body. Not enough clarity to know for sure.

Comment: Could you please provide a visual of what you're trying to do? Like a simple wire frame. Depending on what you're ultimately attempting to do, you could use a grid system from a framework like [Bootstrap (Grid)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/), [Bootstrap (Cards)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/), [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/), etc.

Comment: @hunferstar you may be right, a grid may be simpler if using a framework, however, I think in vanilla absolute positioning will be easier to understand and more straightforward especially for a beginner

Comment: @JuanAntonioOrozco I primarily mention it now as absolute positioning can be difficult to make responsive.